# .gltf object black on loading in three.js

Tags: three.js, gltf

Here is my scene and apply light.

```
scene = new THREE.Scene();
defaultCamera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, container.offsetWidth / container.offsetHeight, 0.01, 100 );

// defaultCamera.up = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 );
scene.add( defaultCamera );
camera = defaultCamera;

var sceneInfo = sceneList[index];
var spot1 = null;
var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 1 );
light.position.set( 10, 10, 10 );
scene.add( light );
```

After this i am loading the `.gltf` model using `gltf2loader`. My model is black in Android. Does anyone have a solution? Please help

Comment: Does it only happen on Android? Maybe your problem is related to the following issue: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/14137. Does it work if you create your `WebGLRenderer` like this: `var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { precision: 'mediump' } );`

Comment: Is the model also black on https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/? If so, are you able to share the model?

Comment: @Mugen87 ..Thxxx. its working after creating the WebGLRenderer using   { precision: 'mediump' }..